# How to get a single row of record with multiple relationship of tables?

Tags: mysql

Table 1 :  User_Profile

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User_profile_id   | Profile_form_id |   Email       |   Zipcode   |   Firstname | Lastname
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1                 | 4               |john@gmail.com |  123456     |  john       | peter 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-

Table 2 :  Profile_attribute_form

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
profile_attribute_id   | Profile_attribute_name |  profile_form_id 
-------------------------------------------------------------------

1                      | Address                |  4
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2                      | Phone Number           |  4
------------------------------------------------------------------
3                      | City                   |  4
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table 3 :  User_Profile_attribute

---

```
User_profile_id        | Profile_attribute_id   |  profile_attribute_value 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

1                      | 1                      |  23,Times road
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                      | 2                      |  9786530874
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                      | 3                      |  New York
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Needed Final Result :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User_profile_id|Profile_form_id|Email |Zipcode|Firstname|Lastname|Address|PhoneNumber|City
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1              |4              |gm.com|123456 |john     |peter   |addr1  |9786530874 |NewY 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to i build the mysql query for the above result.

Comment: I guess you've copied Table3 columns names from Table2?

Comment: Is the attribute_id always the same (1=Address,2=Phone,3=City)? Is there only ever one of each attribute associated with each user_profile? Does every attribute always exist or could some be missing?

Comment: yes correct i will re edit now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are need to do is `JOIN` the tables and then `PIVOT` the data.  However MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function but you can replicate the functionality using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement.

If you know the values to turn into columns then you can use the following:

```
select up.user_profile_id,
  up.profile_form_id,
  up.email,
  up.zipcode,
  up.firstname,
  up.lastname,
  min(case when paf.Profile_attribute_name= 'Address' 
            then upa.profile_attribute_value end) as Address,
  min(case when paf.Profile_attribute_name= 'Phone Number' 
            then upa.profile_attribute_value end) as PhoneNumber,
  min(case when paf.Profile_attribute_name= 'City' 
            then upa.profile_attribute_value end) as City
from user_profile up
left join Profile_attribute_form paf
  on up.Profile_form_id = paf.Profile_form_id
left join User_Profile_attribute upa
  on paf.profile_attribute_id = upa.Profile_attribute_id
  and up.User_profile_id = upa.User_profile_id
group by up.user_profile_id,
      up.profile_form_id,
      up.email,
      up.zipcode,
      up.firstname,
      up.lastname
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b27f/3)

Now if you want to perform this dynamically, meaning you do not know ahead of time the columns to transpose, then you should review the following article:

[Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

Your code would look like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'min(case when paf.Profile_attribute_name = ''',
      paf.Profile_attribute_name,
      ''' then upa.profile_attribute_value end)  AS ',
      replace(paf.Profile_attribute_name, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from user_profile up
left join Profile_attribute_form paf
  on up.Profile_form_id = paf.Profile_form_id;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('select up.user_profile_id,
              up.profile_form_id,
              up.email,
              up.zipcode,
              up.firstname,
              up.lastname, ', @sql, '
           from user_profile up
           left join Profile_attribute_form paf
             on up.Profile_form_id = paf.Profile_form_id
           left join User_Profile_attribute upa
             on paf.profile_attribute_id = upa.Profile_attribute_id
             and up.User_profile_id = upa.User_profile_id
           group by up.user_profile_id,
                 up.profile_form_id,
                 up.email,
                 up.zipcode,
                 up.firstname,
                 up.lastname');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b27f/11)

Comment: how to i use it in magento can you have any idea in magento queries.

Comment: @JohnPeter I am not familiar with magento

Comment: It's Ok dude if you got the magento answer for this means post that too in this page.